# Javascript prompt() alternative - Waiting for user response

Tags: javascript, input

I would like to ask series of questions to users in one function.

If I use prompt(), it is possible to ask all the questions in one function.

```
function question(){
    var name = prompt("Enter your name");
    var age = prompt("Enter your age");
}
```

But if I try to use input tag, this is impossible.

```
function question(){
    document.write("Enter your name");

    // you can't wait until the user responds. It will simply execute all the lines at once. 

    name = document.getElementById("input").value;
    document.write("Enter your age");
    age = document.getElementById("input").value;
}
```

If I do this, I can't use input tag to ask questions to users in one function. How can I wait until the user responds?

Answer (score 2):

To chain prompts you can do something like:

```
const name = prompt("Enter your name");
if (!!name) {
    const age = prompt("Enter your age");
    if(!!age){
      ...
    }
}
```

Or if you can use rxjs 5.5+ in your project you can use an observable to wait for the first prompt.
For example:

```
of(prompt("Enter your name"))
.pipe(first(), filter((name) => !!name))
.subscribe((name) => {
    var age = prompt("Enter your age")
    if(age) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep all your input boxes disabled except the first one. The second one can be enabled upon the user response to the first one. The line of inputs will go on like this.

Here is a little demonstration. Please note this is only a sample code which shows you the design pattern.

```
<input id="name"></input> <button onClick="getInput()">Ok</button>

<input id="address"></input> <button onClick="getInput()" disabled>Ok</button>
```

and in JS

```
var name, address;

functon getInput() {

    name = document.getelementById("name").value;
    address = document.getElementById("address").value;

    if (address !== "")
        document.getElementById("address").removeAttribute("disabled");   

}
```

There are many advance methods than this is available in JS. But probably you should study this pattern first.

Answer (score 0):

You cant take 2 different values from the same input in a function. You should create another input or some button to differentiate variables. For example:`
    
        
        
        
    
    
        
            Enter your name
            
        
        
            Enter your age
            
        
        Save
    
    
        var bSave = window.document.getElementById('bSave');
        bSave.addEventListener("click", question);

```
    var newName = window.document.getElementById('iName');
    var newAge = window.document.getElementById('iAge');

    function question() {
        name=newName.value;
        age=newAge.value;
    }
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

`document.write()` is to writes HTML not for asking user input like `prompt()`. what you need is input validation before user submit the form like

```
function checkQuestion(){
  if(document.getElementById("name").value == "")
    alert('name empty');
  if(document.getElementById("age").value == "");
    alert('age empty');
}
```